# Load two HTML documents at once ( Load iframe contents from string )

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a rather strange need. I need to be able to render two documents at once in the same browser window, but it is not as simple as it sounds.

In the framework that I'm using, enabling debug mode will cause errors to render as an HTML document, displaying a pretty error report page, however there is also the non-debug mode page that I want to display as well with a button to switch between the two.

Basically I have this idea that if I could use an `iframe`, but input a raw string inside it instead of loading an URL that would be exactly what I'm looking for. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to be careful to escape your string.

```
<iframe src="javascript: '<html><head><title>iframe</title></head><body>IFRAME</body></html>'"></iframe>
```

The string inside the single quotes must be escaped properly for this to work.